# Heroku Node.js app refused to apply style because its MIME type

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I am an extremely new beginner with Node.js and Express.  I am getting these errors from the console.

> Refused to apply style from
>   'https://brawlhallastats.herokuapp.com/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME
>   type and strict MIME checking are enabled.

The CSS loads how it should be locally, but when I look at the deployed app on Heroku, it just shows plain HTML with no styling.  Why is this?  I have no idea why and would greatly appreciate some help as I've been searching for help and could not find a direct answer that applies to me.

I believe the problem persists somewhere in the code below.  For reference, this is my layout:

```
    C:/
        index.html
        server.js
        package.json
        .gitignore
        assets
            css
                all_the_css_files in here
        node_modules
```

```html
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const path = require('path');

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
    });

    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, function(){
        console.log('Your node js server is running');
    });
```

I expected the website to load with all the styles correctly.  Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it is heroku related?

Comment: Please share how are you importing stylesheets in your index.html

Comment: Yes, sorry, Updated the page with import example.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and I am writing the concise answer here as people new to express will probably run into this as well.

I was running into this problem because I needed to set a public folder.  All I did was create a folder named public, put assets inside public, then include this line into the server.js file.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was,
instead Of:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

I used:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

now everything working correctly