# React router not loading dynamic url in production

Tags: reactjs, heroku, react-router-dom

I have a url with paramenters in my react routes.
[image: App Routes]

I can access the route via {Link} from react router dom as shown below. The page loads upon button click.
[image]

However when I refresh the page or try to access the URL via the address bar, I get a blank page and this error message
[image]

It works fine locally but the blank page comes up in production. I am hosting the website on heroku.

Comment: The error logs are not due to react router. Problem is the way you are serving the static files. You need to fix that first. The below link might be useful,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56981150/heroku-node-js-app-refused-to-apply-style-because-its-mime-type

Comment: @Drew Reese. All other pages are loading except this particular details page. I dunno if that means the routing works or not

Comment: Ah, I see, I didn't "enbiggen" your screencaps. Yeah, seems to be an issue with how the static assets are handled. Check the link in the other comment. Also, check what all the errors link to or reference. Can you update your question to include that `BeatDetailPage`?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle it is to add a `base` tag in your `index.html`.

```
<base href="/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem using the solution in the link below. I initially set my homepage to "." in my package.json and eventually changed it to my app domain

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66950806/6542175